# In python, can I return a child instance when instantiating its parent?

Tags: python, class

I have a zoo with animals, represented by objects. Historically, only the `Animal` class existed, with animal objects being created with e.g. `x = Animal('Bello')`, and typechecking done with `isinstance(x, Animal)`.

Recently, it has become important to distinguish between species. `Animal` has been made an ABC, and all animal objects are now instances of its subclasses such as `Dog` and `Cat`.

This change allows me to create an animal object directly from one of the subclasses, e.g. with `dog1 = Dog('Bello')` in the code below. This is cheap, and I can use it as long as I know what kind of animal I'm dealing with. Typechecking `isinstance(dog1, Animal)` still works as before.

However, for usibility and backwards compatibility, I also want to be able to call `dog2 = Animal('Bello')`, have *it* (from the input value) determine the species, and return a `Dog` instance - even if this is computationally more expensive.

**I need help with the second method.**

Here is my code:

```py
class Animal:
    def __new__(cls, name):
        if cls is not Animal:  # avoiding recursion
            return super().__new__(cls)

        # Return one of the subclasses
        if name.lower() in ['bello', 'fido', 'bandit']:  # expensive tests
            name = name.title()  # expensive data correction
            return Dog(name)
        elif name.lower() in ['tiger', 'milo', 'felix']:
            # ...

    name = property(lambda self: self._name)
    present = lambda self: print(f"{self.name}, a {self.__class__.__name__}")
    # ... and (many) other methods that must be inherited


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = f"Mr. {name}"  # cheap data correction
    # ... and (few) other dog-specific methods


class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = f"Dutchess {name}"  # cheap data correction
    # ... and (few) other cat-specific methods


dog1 = Dog("Bello")
dog1.present()  # as expected, prints 'Mr. Bello, a Dog'.
dog2 = Animal("BELLO")
dog2.present()  # unexpectedly, prints 'Mr. BELLO, a Dog'. Should be same.
```

Remarks:

- **In my use-case, the second creation method is by far the more important one.**
- What I want to achieve is that calling `Animal` return a subclass, `Dog` in this case, initialized with manipulated arguments (`name`, in this case)
- So, I'm looking for a way to keep the basic structure of the code above, where the parent class can be called, but just always returns a child instance.
- Of course, this is a contrived example ;)

Many thanks, let me know if more information is helpful.

---

## Suboptimal solutions

#### factory function

```py
def create_animal(name) -> Animal:
    # Return one of the subclasses
    if name.lower() in ['bello', 'fido', 'bandit']: 
        name = name.title() 
        return Dog(name)
    elif name.lower() in ['tiger', 'milo', 'felix']:
        # ...

class Animal:
    name = property(lambda self: self._name)
    present = lambda self: print(f"{self.name}, a {self.__class__.__name__}")
    # ... and (many) other methods that must be inherited

class Dog(Animal):
    # ...
```

This breaks backward compatibility by no longer allowing **the creation** of animals with a `Animal()` call. Typechecking is still possible

I prefer the symmetry of being able to call a specific species, with `Dog()`, or use the more general `Animal()`, in the exact same way, which does not exist here.

#### factory funcion, alternative

Same as previous, but change the name of the `Animal` class to `AnimalBase`, and the name of the `create_animal` function to `Animal`.

This fixes the previous problem, but breaks backward compatibility by no longer allowing **typechecking** with `isinstance(dog1, Animal)`.

Comment: Are you essentially looking to implement the factory pattern?

Comment: You may be able to do this with `__new__`, but I'd stronly suggest a seperate factory method to reduce circular dependencies

Comment: Hmm am I? Maybe I am . You are talking about solution 1a, is that correct? It breaks the symmetry, of being able to call a specific species, with `Dog()`, or use the more general `Animal()`, in the exact same way. Which I would prefer to keep, if possible.

Comment: I agree with the others: a factory function is the way to go. I also recommend to make Animal abstract

Comment: The problem with trying to use `__new__` like this is that `Animal.__new__`, inherited by `Dog`, is still how a new instance of `Dog` gets created. Now you have one method trying to do two entirely different things, depending on the value of its `cls` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I went with a class decorator:

```py
# defining the decorator

def dont_init_twice(Class):
    """Decorator for child classes of Animal, to allow Animal to return a child instance."""
    original_init = Class.__init__
    Class._initialized = False

    def wrapped_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self._initialized:
            object.__setattr__(self, "_initialized", True)  #works also on frozen dataclasses
            original_init(self, *args, **kwargs)

    Class.__init__ = wrapped_init

    return Class


# decorating the child classes

@dont_init_twice
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = f"Mr. {name}"

@dont_init_twice
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = f"Dutchess {name}"
```

IMO, this is the cleanest and least invasive solution.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer after receiving more information in the comments and after the question has been updated:

```
class Animal:
    def __new__(cls, name):
        if cls is not Animal:  # avoiding recursion
            return super().__new__(cls)

        # Return one of the subclasses
        if name.lower() in ['bello', 'fido', 'bandit']:  # expensive tests
            name = name.title()  # expensive data correction
            return Dog(name)
        elif name.lower() in ['tiger', 'milo', 'felix']:
            name = name.title()  # expensive data correction
            return Cat(name)    # ...
    # ...


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        # Prevent double __init__
        if not hasattr(self, '_name'):
            self._name = f"Mr. {name}"  # cheap data correction
    # ... and (few) other dog-specific methods


class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        # Prevent double __init__
        if not hasattr(self, '_name'):
            self._name = f"Dutchess {name}"  # cheap data correction
    # ... and (few) other cat-specific methods
```

Original answer below:

---

I would generally advocate for using a class method as an alternate constructor instead of writing a `__new__` or `__init__` that does nontrivial work. In this case, it would be a static method.

For example:

```
class Animal:
    @staticmethod
    def from_name(name):
        # Return one of the subclasses
        if name.startswith("dog_"):  # very expensive tests
            name = name[4:].lower()  # very expensive data correction
            return Dog(name)
        elif name.startwith("cat_"):
            pass
            # ..

# Use like this:
dog2 = Animal.from_name("dog_BELLO")
dog2.present()
```

However, in this particular case we have an example from Python's standard library: pathlib. If you instantiate a `Path`, it will actually return a `WindowsPath` or `PosixPath` depending on your platform, both of which are subclasses of `Path`. [This is how it is done](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/19abf691fe1d59a58882c09e9624fb1ffb910e57/Lib/pathlib.py#L868-L875):

```
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls is Path:
            cls = WindowsPath if os.name == 'nt' else PosixPath
        self = cls._from_parts(args)
        if not self._flavour.is_supported:
            raise NotImplementedError("cannot instantiate %r on your system"
                                      % (cls.__name__,))
        return self
```

(Where `cls._from_parts` calls `object.__new__`.)

In your case, that would be something like:

```
class Animal:
    def __new__(cls, name):
        if cls is Animal:
            if name.startswith("dog_"):  # very expensive tests
                name = name[4:].lower()  # very expensive data correction
                cls = Dog
            elif name.starstwith("cat_"):
                pass # ...
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self.name = name
        return self
```

Note that in this case you should not define an `__init__`, because it would be called with the *original* arguments, not the modified ones.

Comment: Be careful with the last example (which has a typo, as it needs tor return `self`). Using `x = Animal(...)` will still cause `__init__` to invoked when `Animal.__new__` returns any instance of `Animal` (including instances of subclasses of `Animal`)

Comment: That is what I get for writing this in a hurry, you're right. And if you need `Animal('dog_lassie')` to return the same as `Dog('lassie')`, you need to set the name in `__new__` rather than in `__init__`, because otherwise it would initialise it like it would `Dog('dog_lassie')`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! In the `Path` example, users don't care if they receive a `WindowsPath` or a `PosixPath`, as long as the same methods and attributes are available. This is a lot like my actual use case; my users care about creating an `Animal`, and not about the implementation details and if they receive a `Dog` or a `Cat`. (maybe my example was not considered very carefully in that regard)

Comment: It is not possible to use the child class' __init__ method to initialise the objects? I do need to do some light massaging of name before storing it (not shown in my example). Also, I'm trying to make these frozen classes, so no setting of dog.name after the object is initialized. Sorry for the additional conditions; I didn't think they'd be relevant

Comment: (I've slightly changed my question to reflect my previous point. I'd also add raise Errors on `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` to ensure frozenness, but I don't want to detract from the main question.)

Comment: @ElRudi `__init__` receives the original arguments passed to the type. I think I may know what you need, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is a fun question, so i came up with an answer that might work for you.

the idea here is to override `__call__` to parse the `name` arg to get the class and animal name and then dispatch to the correct class with the animal name.

```
from __future__ import annotations


class AnimalMeta(type):
    def __call__(cls, name):
        cls_name, *animal_name = cls._parse_name(name)
        if res := cls._registry.get(cls_name):
            name = animal_name.pop()
        return type.__call__(res or cls, name)


class Animal(metaclass=AnimalMeta):
    _registry = {}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kw):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kw)
        cls._registry[cls.__name__.lower()] = cls

    @classmethod
    def _parse_name(cls, name) -> tuple[str, str]:
        return name.split("_", maxsplit=1)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{type(self).__name__}(name={self.name!r})"


class Dog(Animal):
    ...


class Wombat(Animal):
    ...



animal = Animal("jeb")
dog = Animal("dog_doggo")
wombat = Animal("wombat_wombotron")

print(Animal._registry)
print(animal)
print(dog)
print(wombat)
```

output:

```
{'dog': <class '__main__.Dog'>, 'wombat': <class '__main__.Wombat'>}
Animal(name='jeb')
Dog(name='doggo')
Wombat(name='wombotron')
```

note: this is generally too much magic for my liking, but it is a way to do what you want.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @acushner! I agree it's a lot of magic :) I'm certainly having trouble following it.  Is there a way to "respect"/use the subclasses' `__init__` method? I changed the example slightly to better reflect my actual use-case.

Comment: `__new__` is already there as the way to customize object creation in a class.

Comment: @ElRudi yes, you just write the `__init__` method and it will be called...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the wanted functionality by checking, if the instance did already pass through the `Dog.__init__` method. For this, I  added 3 lines in the code of this method, indicated below.

```py
class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        if hasattr(self, '_initialized'):  # <-- new
            return                         # <-- new
        self._initialized = True           # <-- new
        self._name = f"Mr. {name}"


dog1 = Dog("Bello")
dog1.present()  # as expected, prints 'Mr. Bello, a Dog'.
dog2 = Animal("BELLO")
dog2.present()  # as wanted, also prints 'Mr. Bello, a Dog'.  # <--!
```

As these lines need to be added to each child class, it might make sense to create a decorator, like so:

```py
def dont_initialize_twice(__init__):
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(self, "_initialized"):
            return
        __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._initialized = True

    return wrapped

class Dog:
    @dont_initialize_twice
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = f"Mr. {name}"

class Cat:
    @dont_initialize_twice
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = f"Dutchess {name}"
```

If there is a good reason, why this is bad practice, and a better solution exists, I'd really like to hear it.

Comment: Ah, I see you have figured out a similar solution yourself in the meantime.